# Any tips for embedding ip cam preview into website?

Tags: javascript, html, wordpress, webcam

I have recently struggled with embedding ip cameras (3 of them, to be exact), onto our website which uses free wordpress edition (so plugins are out of the way).

I have tried the most common method, which is to set the cameras to upload an image every second to a folder and then refresh that image with javascript code and extending the image URL with ?r={random int}.

Unfortunately, there was a sync issue, so the image came always either half loaded or corrupted, posibbly due to upload and timing issues between the two of them.

Any tips how to create smooth, at least 2-10 fps preview?

Thanks a bunch.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.